# Keeping battery charged at certain level

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery

I keep my MBA 2013 plugged in most of the time. AFAIK for a long term it is better to keep modern battery around 40%. I have seen that some other laptop manufacturers added feature to their drivers to prevent battery charging over certain level. Is there anything similar available for mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 40% charged state is applicable for *Lithium-Ion batteries **only if you're going to remove the battery and put it in long term storage without using it.*** Refer [How to Prolong Lithium-based Batteries](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries). In the case of MacBook models, [Apple recommends storing the batteries at 50% charge](https://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html) if you do not plan to use it for more than six months.

For normal usage, Apple recommends that you run the laptop on battery once in a while and also do a full discharge and recharge to calibrate the battery (full discharge/recharge means running it down till the computer automatically goes to sleep or shuts down due to low battery and then recharging it completely to 100% in one go).

[Apple laptop batteries - Standard Maintenance](https://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html)

> For proper maintenance of a lithium-based battery, it’s important to keep the electrons in it moving occasionally. Apple does not recommend leaving your portable plugged in all the time. An ideal use would be a commuter who uses her notebook on the train, then plugs it in at the office to charge. This keeps the battery juices flowing. If on the other hand, you use a desktop computer at work, and save a notebook for infrequent travel, Apple recommends charging and discharging its battery at least once per month.

See [Apple's guide on Notebook batteries](https://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html) for detailed information.

Comment: That was a good answer (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge. The MacBooks already do some management of charging, for example if the battery is almost full it will not start charging to 100%, to save charging cycles.

Also, to my knowledge modern batteries die by age, mostly independently to the charging and discharging cycles. But I might be wrong there.